# Enumerate through map to build list

Tags: javascript, loops, ionic-framework

Im trying to create a `<ion-list/>` with `<ion-items/>` by enumerating though a Javascript Map.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>  
</ion-list>
```

This (slightly altered) example of the Ionic docs shows how to iterate through an array.
But if I have a Map as the source (no, i unfortunately can't change it to an array), how can I loop through the Map and create an `<ion-item/>` for every value in the map?

Comment: You can't. Check this out: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-ngfor-array-with-unique-values-6b15478d6484

Comment: Try "let [key, item] of items"

Comment: I did a workaround for now by using Array.from() and putting the Map in it. This Temparray is obviously nested so I use `<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of tempArray">` to iterate through it and then `{{item[1].title}}`